# error message hide using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my simple search box with error message. error message should not appear on load. if input is empty when button clicked, message should appear.

Why in this code error message appear on load though it has be kept hidden.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#error-msg').hide();
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/xfdx7/

Comment: You need to add the jquery library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need jquery to do that. Keep it simple, add the css in beginning:

```
 #error-msg{
   display:none;
 }
```

and click button code:

```
$('.input-group-btn').click(function(){
 if(!$('#url-input-box').val().length){
  $('#error-msg').show();
 }else{
   $('#error-msg').hide();
 }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N8Gmp/)**

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing parenthesis.

[**Side Note:** It can be easily identified by looking at the errors displaying on the console.]

Try,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#error-msg').hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xfdx7/1/)

Comment: any help if to show error when button is cliked and box is empty.

Comment: You are making this question as a chameleon question.. Please ask your new problem as a newer question.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Theres an syntax error in your code..

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#error-msg').hide();
   });
```

document.ready should end with )};
iam attaching a plunkr showing the error when the input is empty..hope you find it useful.
http://plnkr.co/edit/eR27Ti6Dmegh3OXQuDHR?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You are missed close bracket and in your fiddle you haven't included jQuery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#error-msg').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, need to include jQuery libray file to access jQuery functions.

I have updated your code in below link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#error-msg").hide();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfdx7/4/